# On-chip Co-planar Waveguide Design on Si – SiO2 Substrate

Tags: rf, analog, microwave, high-frequency, high-speed

I want to design, simulate, and fabricate on-chip Coplanar waveguides (no bottom ground) on a Silicon Dioxide layer 5um thick on a Silicon 500um thick wafer. The metal electrodes will be 1um thick gold. I am aware that I can indeed simulate this. And I am doing this with Sonnet EM software. My question is does the Silicon Dioxide layer need to be considered in the design and simulation? Will the RF signal be affected by such a thin oxide layer, since it is 100 times thinner than the Bulk Silicon? I want a bandwidth of 10 GHz through this CPW. So operating frequency 0 - 10 GHz.

Any help is appreciated.